# How to listen to keyboard events on the system level via Node.js?

Tags: node.js, windows, chromium, keyboard-events

I play with `CDP` and `Puppeteer` libraries with `Node.js`. I want to capture keyboard event within browser window (**not** `window` or `document` objects at webpage context) context - so when I am in Chromium DevTools (runned by `Puppeteer`) and press i.e *Ctrl + E* combination (which fires Performance test in Timeline tab) I would like to capture this event.

I managed to do that with `RobotJS` library, but it does not support the latest Node version (v8.7), so after updating Node I cannot even install it. I found `iohook` lib, but it does not support latest Node neither as well as `Windows` (which I use).

`CDP` and `Puppeeteer` libs AFAIK supports only events within webpage context only.
I also tried Node native module `readline`, which however captures keyboard events in console, but not in browser window.

Is there any way to capture/listen to keyboard events in Chrome/Chromium browser window via Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

iohook at this moment support Node.js 8+ but still don't have prebuilt versions for windows.

You can try use [windows fork of iohook](https://github.com/renjfk/iohook)

Or you can compile original iohook in your windows machine